# Icon needs to wrap two lines with :before pseudo css element

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-selectors, pseudo-element

For my current use case, I have to set the inner html of my element programatically due to it using markdown:

```
<div
    className='quote-copy'
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
       __html: body?.childMarkdownRemark?.html,
    }}
/>
```

In this element, I have to make sure a quote icon appears over the first two lines of the set paragraph like this:
[image]

However, when trying this, I only managed to get it working on the first line of the paragraph like this:
[image]

By using the following code in my scss file:

```
.quote-copy {
  > :first-child {
    &::before {
      content: '';
      overflow: hidden;
      display: inline-block;
      background: url('../../../assets/icons/quote.svg') no-repeat center;
      object-fit: contain;
      width: 60px;
      height: 40px;
      background-size: 60px 40px;
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can make the quote icon appear over the first two lines of copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the "float:left" on your pseudo element

Comment: Yes! that seemed to work! For some reason I thought floats had no purpose at all anymore. Turns out I'm wrong :D